# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed. you can help me

Tags: c#

i don't know whats the problem , you can help me to find solution , and fix the problem , the Decrypt() is mathod to decrypt code

```
var test = Decrypt(cli);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand id_c = new SqlCommand("Select * From ResearcherInformation where Email='" + test + "'", conn);
myReader = id_c.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
    {
        var idid = myReader["Id_Researcher"].ToString();
        conn.Close();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('access');", true);
    }
    myReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: You're calling `conn.Close();` in the while loop and also after. Try removing from inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

You're closing the connection in the middle of your loop:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    var idid = myReader["Id_Researcher"].ToString();
    conn.Close();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('access');", true);
}
```

Which is why the connection is closed as soon as you loop over the reader a second time.  Don't do that:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    var idid = myReader["Id_Researcher"].ToString();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('access');", true);
}
```

Close the connection *after* you use it, not *while* you use it.

---

A few additional things worth noting:

1. Your are relying on SQL-injectable practices.  This is both a major security vulnerability and a very common source of bugs.  Use query parameters to treat values as *values* instead of as *executable code*.  This is a good place to start for examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples  A Google search for "C# parameterized query" will find more.
2. Take a look at the use of `using` statements for things like your `SqlConnection` object and other objects which implement `IDisposable`.
3. You don't use your `idid` variable for anything, so you can just get rid of it.  You also never use `dt`, so you can get rid of that too.

Comment: It's also worth noting the SQL concatenation vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

You getting this : **Error. Invalid attemp to call read.**
You make a mistake in your code. 
The Reader object requires a opened connection and you make a mistake that you closed a connection inside a loop that's why you getting this exception.

```
Sqlconnection connection = new Sqlconnection("//..") // Provide a Correct Connection string.
var test = Decrypt(cli);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
connection.Open();

// Don't goes for this approach. always try to use Store Procedure instead to this.
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * From ResearcherInformation where Email='" + test + "'", connection);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   var idid = myReader["Id_Researcher"].ToString();
   // connection.Close(); this is not the a place for closing a connection.
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('access');", true);
}
reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```